# 1D Kinematics problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity

The position of a particle in meters moving along the x-axis is given by:
$x = 3(t − 2)^2 − 12$ for $0 \le t \le 15$

How can I find the velocity of the particle when it is passing through the point $x = 0$ at time $t > 0$? And what is the position of the particle when speed is $0$ at time $t >  0$?

I have no idea how to go about solving this and my textbook honestly is useless.

Comment: Solve for t using x=0 and differentiate the equation wrt time. Substitute value of t into the derivative. Also your equation looks weird.

Comment: I wonder if the $3(t-2)2$ term is supposed to be $3(t-2)^2$.  That would make a lot more sense than what's written.

Comment: @Sean Maybe. Unless the OP changes it we won't know.

Comment: The text is probably not useless. If you look carefully you can find that `velocity = time derivative of position`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed through the following steps:

- Differentiate your equation with respect to t to get some relation between $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $t$. Name this equation (2) and the given one (1).
- Now solve the first equation for $x=0$ and you will get a real positive value of $t$.
- Put this value of $t$ in equation (2) to get the answer to your first question.
- Now solve equation (2) for $\frac{dx}{dt} = 0$ and you will again get a real positive value of $t$ as your solution.
- Put this value of $t$ in equation (1) to get the second answer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since v= dx/dt, then $x= 3t^2 - 12t$, thefore $v = 6t - 12$, solving for t when $x = 0$, we get $t = 0,4$, taking t = 4 to satisfy the condition $t > 0$, therefore, $v = 24-12 = 12m/s$ ?

Comment: Not sure how to figure out t for the position part...

Comment: I think I got it since $\frac{dx}{dt}$ = $6t - 12$ then, $6t - 12$ =$0$ = $2s$, therefore,  $x = -12$?

Comment: Yes $v = 12m/s$ and $x = -12m$. So you got both of them correct. All's well that ends well !!

Comment: Woah, that's fun thank you. Im trying to figure out the Total distance between t = 0, t =15. Would it simply be calculating x(0), x(15), and adding them? For the absolute value result?

Comment: Don't add them. Rather subtract them. I mean $x(15)-x(0)$ = total distance

Comment: That makes sense if it we're displacement? $\Delta x$ = $x_f - x_i$ ? I'm confused why I would subtract. I can take the abs.value of each and just add them since it's distance.

Comment: See, this is one dimensional motion with constant acceleration. And for your problem there is no change of direction of motion. So displacement is same as distance.Moreover what you are suggesting is exactly what I am telling. Try and check it out. Both will give the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that velocity is given by $$v \equiv \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
As a result, to determine your particle velocity at a given time, simple differentiate your position equation, and then solve for your particular condition ($x=0$)